# Magento2 how to edit the item.phtml template for Related Products and Upsell Porducts?

Tags: magento2, related-products

In Magento2 I've enabled the Related Products and Upsell Products blocks. Everything's fine except for the template of the single item. I want to change that to another custom one.

Here in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/slider/product-slider.phtml`

The template for the items in the file above is declared here: `$itemTemplate = $block->getData('item_template') ?? 'Magento_Catalog::product/list/item.phtml';`

And this template is the same used for the catalog_category_view.xml

If I try to change that `item.phtml` file with another custom one in the same directory it doesn't work. Is there any way to override this?

Thanks guys.

Comment: What do you mean with "template of the single item", the product page?

Comment: I mean the template for the product box(image, wishlist button ecc..) inside the carousel

Comment: Inside your theme the file should be named items.phtml inside Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml, inside the Items.phtml there's the generation of the lists of related, upsell , try check the phtml inside there, and rewrite the items.phtml placing the file in the same path on your theme

Comment: Hi Alan, I've checked that file, it's inside `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml`. Copied it, pasted into `app/design/frontend/Magenio/aldo/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml`. I've seen in this file that there's a switch to handle all the cases, tried to change the title for the "Related Products" block but the title stays the same, for example. So I need to figure out how to fix this. However thanks a lot for the quick response :)